# Qt Creator not able to view source code

Tags: qt

I have started to develop an app using Qt Creator, and I am dealing with signals and slots.  The problem I have is that I have no way to figure out how to view the code generated from my .ui file I am building.  I want to edit some signals and slots but I can't do more than the GUI stuff.  Is there a way to view all the source code that is generated when I build my .ui file in creator, or do I have to use another part of the Qt suite?

Comment: Moreover, doesn't Qt create the corresponding code in the header and main files when you build a signal and slot?

Answer (score 0):

The `.ui` file is fed to `uic` to generate `.ui.h` file. You should be including that file in your code. Place the cursor over the name of the include file within the `#include "foo.ui.h"` line, and press F2 to see the contents of the file.

There is no other output from a `.ui` file. "Qt", specifically the Makefile for your project, doesn't generate anything besides a `.ui.h` file.